# Does "id" become unique if the display property of the element with the same id is set to "none"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Let's say you have a DIV element with `id="row"` in your document. And then you inserted a new DIV with the same id name and set the display property of the previous DIV to `"none"`. Does that id of the newly created DIV become unique?

Comment: No. The "display" property is something that the DOM doesn't care about.

Comment: Styling doesn't affect the uniqueness of elements in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Display:none` is just a CSS property. Which means the element doesn't render in the view. But it exists in DOM. It exists in your syntax, and JS can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

No..It doesn't matter if they are hidden(display :"none")or not they are still in the document. Even if they are created dynamically they shouldn't have the same ID. "it's not a valid markup"